# Creating a Pandas Dataframe from an API Endpoint in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I am trying to convert API into pandas DataFrame.

sample API : [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate:[20040101+TO+20210629])+AND+PREDNISOLONE](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate:%5B20040101+TO+20210629%5D)+AND+PREDNISOLONE)

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

def callAPI(drug_name, recievedate_from, recievedate_to):

    url='https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate: 
    ['+str(recievedate_from)+'+TO+'+str(recievedate_to)+'])+AND+'+str(drug_name)
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    data = json.load(open(r))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
    print(df)
    
callAPI('PREDNISOLONE', 20040101, 20210629)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict
```

How do I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

- given [response.json()](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) has already called `json.loads()` you should not be calling it yourself
- simplest way to get JSON into a dataframe is [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)
- I've also shown how you can expand embedded lists in the returned structure

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate:[20040101+TO+20210629])+AND+PREDNISOLONE")

df = pd.json_normalize(res.json()["results"])
dfpr = df["patient.reaction"].explode().apply(pd.Series)
dfpd = df["patient.drug"].explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: I tried your code. but I am getting error ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'```

Comment: can't believe it will be this `requests.__version__` 2.25.1 python 3.9.4.  Plus `json()` is a method not an attribute.  restart your kernel and just run my code (assuming you are using jupyter)